# Hibernate. Localization columns. Dynamicaly load

Tags: java, hibernate, internationalization

I have a table countries with columns:

```
id, en, de, fr, ru, lt

id - primary key
en,de,... - localization
```

I want to write Entity like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "countries")
public class EntityCountry {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Localization
    private String name;
```

And get Entity like:

```
Session session = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
EntityCountry e = (EntityCountry) session.createQuery("from EntityCountry where id = 1").setLocalization("en").uniqueResult();
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

Please help how i can do that?

Comment: Can your table structure be changed to something that is more of a 'one-to-many' type of structure between 2 tables?

Comment: maybe. can you give an example?

Comment: You could consider putting your localization fields in a separate table, something with columns like `LOCALE` and `NAME`.  This way you could apply a session filter to restrict the contents of that collection to be based on some `LOCALE` key.

Comment: is this the best practice?